# The PDO extension is not loaded on Shared host

Tags: php, zend-framework, web, pdo

I get this error when i try to run constructor of `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`:

`The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded`

I use a `shared host` and i cannot change the `php.ini`.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a part from changing your hosting provider you could try the following things:

- Use `Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli` (assuming `mysqli` is available)
- Write your own adapter using the `mysql_*`-functions (or use an [existing one](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6208-PHP-Zend-DB-adapter-using-the-original-MySQL-extension.html))
- Try to load the PDO extension dynamically (assuming it is available and enable_dl is on, safe_mode is off):

```
    dl('pdo.so');
    dl('pdo_mysql.so');
```

Comment: where i must write `dl('pdo.so'); dl('pdo_mysql.so');`?

Comment: I think the best place is in your "index.php" before the application's bootstrap method is called. But if you initialize your database in the bootstrap.php you can also put it there right before the database initialization.

Comment: I try this and get this error `Call to undefined function dl() in ...`.

Comment: Regarding the "dl()"-error: apparently dl() is not available on your host. I googled a bit and found [a MySQL-adapter using the mysql_* functions](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6208-PHP-Zend-DB-adapter-using-the-original-MySQL-extension.html). Check it out and see if it works (I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch to Mysqli or another adapter?

Should be fairly simple, depending on the configuration of the Zend application, change the 
db adapter value.

In json type configuration it's

```
"db": {
    "adapter": "mysqli",
    ...
}
```

Php array configuration:

```
 array(
    'database' => array(
        'adapter' => 'Mysqli',
```

Ini type:

```
db.adapter = "Mysqli"
```

This is all, of course, if you are making a db adapter through the configuration and using it as a bootstrap resource. If not, simply instantianate another db adapter:

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli();
```

Comment: `Mysqli` adapter is not available, i get this error `The Mysqli extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded`.